# Kernel Keeps restarting/dying with Numba calculation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I've been using Anaconda to perform some simple gravitational calculations and I wanted to speed up the processes with Numba. So I modified the original result that was in terms of python objects (lists) into one working only with numpy arrays and then used @jit or @njit to speed up the calculations. It seemed to work for rather short calculations but it suddenly broke down for longer calculations and how it mixed with other code. The modules I used were;

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import re
import os
from numba import jit,  njit
```

The gravitational code in terms of python objects was;

```
def verlet_int(u,p,v,t_set,N,k,d,p_num):
    t = t_set[0]
    T = t_set[1]
    dt = t_set[2]
    
    p_prime = []
    v_prime = []
    o = []
    
    a_ik = lambda u,p,k,i,j : (-1)*u[k]*((((p[i][0] - p[k][0])**2) + ((p[i][1] - p[k][1])**2) + ((p[i][2] - p[k][2])**2))**(-1.5))*(p[i][j] - p[k][j])
    
    while t <= T:
        a_1 = []
        a_2 = []
        for i in np.arange(N):
            b_1 = []
            b_2 = []
            for j in [0,1,2]:
                if p_num == -1:
                    b_1.append(p[i][j])
                    b_2.append(v[i][j])
                elif i == p_num:
                    a_1.append(p[i][j])
                    a_2.append(v[i][j])
                v_half = v[i][j] + 0.5*sum([a_ik(u,p,k,i,j) for k in np.delete(np.arange(N),i)])*dt
                p[i][j] = p[i][j] + v_half*dt
                v[i][j] = v_half + 0.5*sum([a_ik(u,p,k,i,j) for k in np.delete(np.arange(N),i)])*dt
            if p_num == -1:
                a_1.append(b_1)
                a_2.append(b_2)
            elif i == p_num:
                pass
        if round(t/dt)%k == 0:
            p_prime.append(a_1)
            v_prime.append(a_2)
        else:
            pass
        t += dt
        t = np.round(t, decimals = d)
    o.append(p_prime)
    o.append(v_prime)
    return o
```

Where, `o[positions (0) or velocities (1)][pick your recorded time step][pick your particle 0...N-1][x (0), y(1), or z(2)]`. That is, if `p_num = -1` and if not then it only recorded positions and velocities for that particle `p_num = 0...N-1`.

The modified code that I jitted was;

```
@jit(debug = True)
def verlet_int_numpy(u,p_v_1,t_i,T,dt,k,dec,p_num):
    times = np.arange(t_i,T,dt)
    p_v = np.copy(p_v_1)
    if p_num == -1:
        storage = np.zeros((round(times.size/k),2,len(u),3))
    else:
        storage = np.zeros((round(times.size/k),2,1,3))
    for tau in range(times.size):
        if tau%k == 0:
            if p_num == -1:
                storage[tau] = p_v
            else:
                storage[tau][0][0] = p_v[0][p_num]
                storage[tau][0][1] = p_v[1][p_num]
        else:
            pass
        for j in range(u.size):
            a_g = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
            for i in  np.delete(np.arange(u.size),j):
                a_g = a_g + u[i]*(((p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j])@(p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j]))**(-1.5))*(p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j])
            v_half = p_v[1][j] + 0.5*a_g*dt
            p_v[0][j] = p_v[0][j] + v_half*dt
            a_g = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0])
            for i in  np.delete(np.arange(u.size),j):
                a_g = a_g + u[i]*(((p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j])@(p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j]))**(-1.5))*(p_v[0][i] - p_v[0][j])
            p_v[1][j] = v_half + 0.5*a_g*dt
    return storage
```

Which I then used in another function that would record down the positions and velocites of each particle separately as panda data frames to my external drive. This being;

```
def setup_csv(i_s,i_v,strings):
    
    r_cm = (1/np.sum(i_s[0]))*np.dot(i_s[0],i_v[0])
    v_cm = (1/np.sum(i_s[0]))*np.dot(i_s[0],i_v[1])
    
    i_v[0] = i_v[0] - r_cm
    i_v[1] = i_v[1] - v_cm
    
    O = verlet_int_numpy(np.array(i_s[0]),i_v,i_s[1],i_s[2],i_s[3],i_s[6],i_s[4],i_s[7])
    
    if i_s[7] == -1:
        for j in np.arange(i_s[0].size):
            D_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = O[:,0,j])
            D_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = O[:,1,j])
    
            D_1.to_csv(r"/Volumes/Storage/Physics Simulations and Research/Gravitational Research/D_test/" + "particle_{}_{}_{}_".format(j,i_s[6],i_s[3]) + strings[0], mode = 'w', header = False, index = None)
            D_2.to_csv(r"/Volumes/Storage/Physics Simulations and Research/Gravitational Research/D_test/" + "particle_{}_{}_{}_".format(j,i_s[6],i_s[3]) + strings[1], mode = 'w', header = False, index = None)
    else:
        D_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = O[:,0,i_s[7]])
        D_2 = pd.DataFrame(data = O[:,1,i_s[7]])
    
        D_1.to_csv(r"/Volumes/Storage/Physics Simulations and Research/Gravitational Research/D_test/" + "particle_{}_{}_{}_".format(i_s[7],i_s[6],i_s[3]) + strings[0], mode = 'w', header = False, index = None)
        D_2.to_csv(r"/Volumes/Storage/Physics Simulations and Research/Gravitational Research/D_test/" + "particle_{}_{}_{}_".format(i_s[7],i_s[6],i_s[3]) + strings[1], mode = 'w', header = False, index = None)
```

Further information on the meaning of the terms is given below for the python list one;

```
#p_pick gives the particle to be recorded from orbit_int_verlet(). It takes values 0,1,...,N-1. It can also take on
#. . . -1 for recording all the possible particle positions/velocites. 
#s_scale gives the magnitude of the random unit vector.
#t_i is the initial time. 
#Usually assume t_o = 0.
#dt is the time step.
#T = total length of time.
#k decides the number of stored values by whether it evenly divides the number of time steps gone by. 
#u are the 'N' number of masses for the bodies. 
#d_places is the number of decimal places to round the time step every loop so as to not accumlate much numerical error.
#i_s = inital_scalars = [u,t_i,T,dt,d_places,s_scale,k,p_pick] 
#strings = [] . . . set of string titles. The first two will be the comparison orbits; position then velocity. 
#. . . the last two will be where the output files for position then velocity will go
#i_v = initial_vectors = np.array([ [[],[],...,[]], [[],[],...,[]] ]) this is 2xNx3 array.
```

The numpy version has it so 'u' is also a numpy array instead of a set. When combined with initial conditions;

```
u = np.array([0.97,0.02,0.01])
orbits = 0.05
dec = 3
T = round( (2*np.pi*(80**(1.5)))/(np.sqrt(0.98))*orbits)
dt = 0.005
p_num = -1
s_scale = 0.1
k = 950
t_i = 0
i_s = [u,t_i,T,dt,dec,s_scale,k,p_num]
i_v = np.array([[[20,0,0],[-40,0,0],[80,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[0,np.sqrt(0.85/40),0],[0,np.sqrt(0.85/80),0]]])
strings = ["comparison_p.csv","comparison_v.csv"]
```

Then as it runs it would rather shortly have a kernel has died come up and say that it would automatically restart. I think the jitting works and there were no exceptions when doing so but something about running it just didn't sit well. I don't know what i'm doing wrong or what is going on at this point and would heavily appreciate some direction here.

Edit:

With a previous run it came up with this error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py in _pseudo_sync_runner(coro)
     66     """
     67     try:
---> 68         coro.send(None)
     69     except StopIteration as exc:
     70         return exc.value

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_async(self, raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures, transformed_cell, preprocessing_exc_tuple)
   3166             # Write output to the database. Does nothing unless
   3167             # history output logging is enabled.
-> 3168             self.history_manager.store_output(self.execution_count)
   3169             # Each cell is a *single* input, regardless of how many lines it has
   3170             self.execution_count += 1

AttributeError: 'ZMQInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'history_manager'
```

Answer (score -1):

try without %matplotlib at the start.

Comment: You didn't give me any explanation of why this would work or what this fixes. . . but it does seem to be working at the moment. So thanks.